# Pan LinearLayout when soft keyboard is opened, don't do anything to RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

My xml contains both a RelativeLayout, which contains a background image, and a LinearLayout which contains a login box:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:id="@+id/back"
android:background="@drawable/a_hdpi">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@drawable/linearlayout_bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:id="@+id/loginbox">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_top_bg"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="#cccccc" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_bg"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:password="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Login" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, when the soft keyboard is opened, it either pans or resizes depending on what option I have set (as per `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`), but what I want to do is PAN the LinearLayout, but leave the RelativeLayout alone, and full size.

Is this possible?  I can't find any other question/answers or guides on how to manage two embedded layouts.